# Why did Thanos wipe out this race?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

Eitri states that Thanos

> Killed 300 of the dwarves, leaving Eitri the lone survivor of the race.

Knowing Thanos' fixation with

> destroying half of each sapient species, why did he choose to commit an apparently unnecessary near genocide of the dwarves?

Comment: Did Eitri exactly say "the lone survivor of his race"? After all, the place he was was a forge, that his workplace. There may be a dwarf planet somewhere else. Also, Thanos had a pragmatical approach in his quest: when encountering an army, or any other obstacle, he would mot count them to kill exactly half of them.

Comment: “destroying half of each sapient species” — is that definitely his obsession? I don’t think he ever specifies what sort of breakdown he’s going for. He tells Tony that he likes him, and that half of humanity will be spared, which could imply he’s open to wiping out all of some species if he feels like it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe Thanos' motivation was to prevent the dwarves from forging a weapon capable of killing him. It appears that

> Eitri was spared out of gratitude for having forged the Infinity Gauntlet, but Thanos still cut off his hands and deactivated the forge just to be certain he couldn't make such a weapon.

I'd say Thanos' fears were correct, given that with Thor's help, Eitri manages to forge Stormbreaker, and

> A single blow from it severely wounds Thanos and *almost* kills him.

Comment: Eitri also shows his hands which appear to be prosthetic and made of a metal (rather than actual arms), saying that Thanos told him that he could have his life but his "arms belong to him". Eitri couldn't forge Stormbreaker himself.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'd still like more of an explanation as to why he didn't kill all of them

Comment: I guess he felt somewhat thankful - enough to leave him alive (with his race now extinct, which could be considered a curse, but maybe not for Thanos who's also in this case), not enough to leave him in his way.